# Windows 7 Screen Saver timeout problems using GPO

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

In our Windows 2003 domain, we are enforcing screensavers with timeouts through GPO.  The settings currently in effect are:

```
Screen Saver = Enabled
Screen Saver executable name = %systemroot%\System32\scrnsave.scr
Password protect the screen saver = Enabled
Screen Saver timeout = 300 seconds
```

This policy works fine with our XP machines and with some of our Windows 7 desktops, but not all of them.  The timeout setting does not work with all of our Windows 7 desktops.  The GPO is applied and the settings look correct. The settings are greyed out and cannot be changed by the users, but the screen savers never come on. If we set the Screen Saver timeout to Not Configured in the GPO and we set the timeout manually it works.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: Is anything running in the background like Windows Media Player, etc?

Also, I've read that it could be a faulty mouse driver, etc.

Comment: are the units not funcioning correctly (with the screensavers i mean) on the same version of windows as the others?  it could be that the names of those flags are different in different versions (proffessional, enterprise, ultimate, etc) or in different update states (sp1, etc).  unlikely, yes, but still a possibility.

Comment: Have you ran gpresult from the group policy management window and see if there are any errors?